# Ofbiz : Getting continuous User login not found exception

Tags: java, exception, ofbiz

The following similar exceptions I'm getting in my log files frequently. Afterwards server itself wont accept any data and sync services are not working, even for valid Userlogin credentials.

Can anyone suggest me what will be the cause for it and how can I resolve it.?

---- exception report ----------------------------------------------------------

Failure in findOne operation for entity [**UserLogin**]: org.ofbiz.entity.transaction.GenericTransactionException: **The current transaction is marked for rollback, not beginning a new transaction and aborting current operation**; the rollbackOnly was caused by: Failure in create operation for entity [InvoiceAttribute]: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: Error while inserting: [GenericEntity:InvoiceAttribute]

Environment : Ubuntu 14.04 
 
Database : MySql v5.6

Comment: Please tell us at least some base details of your installation and environment, release version, used database etc. It's impossible to provide any help without more details.

Comment: @MichaelBrohl we are using Ubuntu 14.04, MySQL v5.6 InnoDb, I don't know OFBiz release version. How can I find it.? can you help me.?

Comment: Maybe too late, but to know the OFBiz version either run
Pre Gradle version: "ant svninfo", then run OFBiz "ant start" and finally look at the bottom of one page (not ecommerce but ERP side).
For Gradle version: same but use svnInfoFooter.

The same kind of commands exist also for Git. To know more about them use either:

Pre Gradle version: ant -p
Gradle version: gradlew task.

Those commands use Windows syntax, for *nix put "./" before them